# Decipher Poorly Written PL/SQL Assignment

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to help a friend with his school work and I'm exhausted trying to figure out what the instructor is asking for.  I'm experienced in SQL but new to Oracle so it's hard for me to interpret these questions. Below is the question that we're on now:

[1 http://puu.sh/hlhcg/65632b5c81.png](http://puu.sh/hlhcg/65632b5c81.png)

First, the "blogid" field does not represent a currency so I think that was a typo... There is one field in the database that does represent a currency so I'll have to assume the instructor means that one.  Can anyone give me an interpretation of the rest of the problem that makes sense to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wild guess would be he wants something like this:

```
22:41:42 (18)SYS@sandbox> l
  1  declare
  2    value number := &value;
  3  begin
  4   dbms_output.put_line(
  5     to_char(value, 'L990.00', 'nls_currency=£')
  6   );
  7* end;
22:41:48 (18)SYS@sandbox> /
Enter value for value: 540
?540.00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
22:41:50 (18)SYS@sandbox> /
Enter value for value: 0
?0.00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

You can use `to_char` in queries either.

p.s. I'd find another instructor unless you're specifically preparing yourself for corporate environment where no one knows what he wants.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the advice, but my friend is nearing the end of his course so I don't think changing instructors is an option.

Comment: People in "corporate environments" know precisely what they want - and change it on a daily basis. :-)